# show property of limits with absolute value

Tags: calculus, limits

Show if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a $ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = |a| $ it looks to obvious but I'd like to know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the following inequality:

$$||x|-|y||\le|x-y|$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $|x|$ is continuous.​​​​

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$||a_n| - |a||\leq |a_n - a|.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Do you know this form of the triangle inequality?
$$\left| |x|-|y| \right| \leq |x-y|
$$